# Recurring error when running Gatsby server with gatsby-source-figma plugin

Tags: gatsby, figma-api

I've been getting this recurring error when trying to run my gatsby server after adding the config for the gatsby-source-figma-plugin. Does anyone have any idea how to get around this?

Missing onError handler for invocation 'building-schema', error was 'Error: Type with name "FigmaELLIPSE" does not exists'. Stacktrace was 'Error: Type with name "FigmaELLIPSE" does not exists